# Open Pdf with Adobe Reader from Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the next problem. I don't have Adobe Reader in my local machine and i have some Webform that show pdf files in fact i can't see this pdf files for it i need to find some way to open this files using the Adobe Reader from the server. Is that posssible? Somebody could show me how do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to use Adobe Reader to display a PDF to another machine through a web page. If this is just for local testing, try using Chrome or Firefox if you can. These have their own PDF readers separate from Adobe.

If you are trying to actually display the content as a non-PDF format, you may want to look into something that will parse the file into HTML. Mozilla's "[pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)" is a good example, and might be of use to you. However, I don't think this is necessary. Nearly all users can view PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PDF Js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) which can render a PDF in a web viewer.